# I am trying to save an image to a file by using opencv python library using cv2.imwrite() function but it shows an error

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save an image to a file by using the OpenCV python library using `cv2.imwrite()` but it shows an error.

The code is :

```
import cv2

# Reading image as gray scale
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg',1)
# saving the image
status = cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg',0,img)

print('the status of the image is : ',status)
```

Error displayed :

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-773a1fcb9cd4> in <module>
      4 img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Joydeep\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg',1)
      5 # saving the image
----> 6 status = cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Joydeep\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg',0,img)
      7 
      8 print('the status of the image is : ',status)

error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Conversion error: params, what: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-inblc7p7\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp:320: error: (-215:Assertion failed) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function 'cv::Mat::copyTo'
> 
>  - Conversion error: params, what: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-inblc7p7\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp:320: error: (-215:Assertion failed) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function 'cv::Mat::copyTo'
>
```

*** What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce), `imwrite` have the following parameters:

```
cv.imwrite( filename, img[, params] )
```

where `params` are the [ImwriteFlags](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac) to specify the output.

so it is probably the `0`, try:

```
status = cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg',img)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use `1` as the second parameter of the `cv2.imread()` method, it will read in the image in full color rather than grayscale; note that `1` is the default value for the flag. In order to read in the image as a grayscale image, use `0`, which is the value for `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`.

Finally, you don't include the `0` when you're writing the image:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg', 0)
status = cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg', img)

print('the status of the image is : ', status)
```

If you prefer to read in the image in color, and only write it out in grayscale, you can use the `cv2.cvtColor` method:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg')
status = cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Person\Pictures\Wallpapers (Space)\Carl Sagan.jpg', cv2.cvtColor(img, 6))

print('the status of the image is : ', status)
```

Where the `6` is the value of `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`.